# How to install facebook event pixel in react component

Tags: reactjs, facebook, ads, google-ads-api

I have a Facebook base code for lead tracking installed in my React app. All I want to do is to  add `fbq('track', 'Lead');` to my `"Thankyou.jsx"` component.

All examples I have seen used NextJs but I'm writing just React and Redux.

How do I add `fbq('track', 'Lead');` in the react component where I want it to reside?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to search for that and I finally found one named react-facebook-pixel